# How do I see/change the Oauth2 callback URL for a connected app?

Tags: oauth2

I created the connected app and everything is working fine. I am able to generate Oauth2 tokens and query objects. However if want to see/change the Oauth2 details like callback URL, I cannot see it in the connected App screen.

My user Id has sys admin rights and it also has "Manage connected Apps rights" by default. What am I missing?

The only settings that I am able to change by going to the "connected app" menu are Oauth policies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to see/change the OAuth details then you need to go to **Setup** > **Create** > **Apps** and select your app from the Connected Apps section, rather than using **Setup** > **Manage Apps** > **Connected Apps** which is what it sounds like you are doing at the moment.

**Note:**
This will only work in the Org that you created the Connected App in, any Orgs that make use of the Connected App cannot change these details.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex. That was the mistake I was making indeed by going to Setup > Manage Apps > Connected Apps instead of Setup > Create > Apps. This is a bit confusing.

Comment: Issue was driving me nuts too, albeit on the new "lightning" GUI.  Figured it out, for this GUI, select Setup and then on (the default) Home tab, on the left-side menu, choose Platform Tools -> Apps -> App Manager, instead of -> Apps -> App Exchange Marketplace -> Connected Apps -> Manage Connected Apps.